# Korean locale doesn't work on Ubuntu headless 16.10

Tags: server, 16.10, remote, locale, headless

[Screenshot of dpkg-reconfigure locales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q0zI.png)

I was trying to get Korean to work on my remote headless server (Ubuntu 16.10, connected to from Win10 with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows) . From the screenshot above, the only idea I have for why it still doesn't work is that there are no default fonts that support Hangul (e.g. when I run `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` there are no charsets that support Hangul) but I can't work out how to add a new one. (note that Korean doesn't work when I use the headless server locally either)

In doing all this, another problem has arisen.
The contents of my `/etc/default/locale` file do not affect the locale at all. For example, `/etc/default/locale` contains:

```
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8
```

from running `update-locale LANG=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8`, but `locale` still reports (both before and after logout/reboot)

```
LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_TIME="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_PAPER="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_NAME="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ko_KR.utf8"
LC_ALL=ko_KR.utf8
```

`/etc/environment` and `~/.bashrc` do not contain anything that affects locale.

The only way I seem to be able to change the locale is by using my `.bashrc` to export the definitions, but this doesn't affect all users. The en_AU locale must be set correctly since it works when set through `.bashrc`.

Where should I look next in troubleshooting this issue?

**Update:**
I just noticed that even when I export with `.bashrc` the LANG field doesn't get updated.

```
export LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
export LC_ALL="en_AU.UTF-8"
```

Output of `locale` after logging out/in:

```
LANG=ko_KR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
...
LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8
```

Comment: I suspect that you export `LANG` from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows when you log in the the server. So try to login without exporting variables (don't know how exactly that is accomplished).

Comment: I've tried commenting out SendEnv in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` locally (Windows) and AcceptEnv in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` remotely (Ubuntu) but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This is odd. Somehow you need to figure out what it is that sets LANG. Otherwise I have a couple of comments: 1. Normally there is no need to set LC_ALL persistently. LANG should be sufficient. 2. To render Hangul, you may want to install the `fonts-nanum` package.

Comment: As far as I could determine, it's impossible to render Hangul with a headless setup because it needs the X server. nanum doesn't provide a console font.